# MKMapView: Customize Current Location's Avatar View

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapview

In recent versions of iOS, sometimes the current user's location (the blue dot) becomes smaller and an "Avatar View" of sorts appears (screenshot below).

Is there a way to set a custom view / picture for this "Avatar View"? (not sure what this view is called, not sure if it is even called an "Avatar View")

[image: Avatar View in Map Kit]

Comment: In mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? you can check if the annotation is of type MKUserLocation and create a custom annotation view for it. Then you can assign a custom view for detailCalloutAccessoryView property of the annotation view.

Comment: @Asteroid – thanks for the note, unfortunately this does not retain the highlighting behavior of the MKAnnotation that comes default with MapKit. Any chance you have another idea?